# How to use dynamic meta tags in react single page application?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, meta-tags, react-helmet

I am using react.js for Single Page Applications.
routing codes are inside the src --> routes.js
I have referred many pages for this one of the pages is https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/
but I don't know where to implement this.
I have done exactly what they mentioned but normally we are using "npm start" to run the front-end.
even after doing " npm run server" it's showing listening on port 3000. but meta tag values are still like this  "***title***_" .

please refer to any ideology to implement this.

[this is the folder structure i have use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCIby.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a react helmet to change the meta content dynamically on each page. In my case, I use the helmet on my header , because all the pages on the site have a header. from the header, we can change the meta content dynamically.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

```
render(){
return(<>
 <Helmet>
<title>{this.state.metaContent.meta_title}</title>
<meta name="title" content={"Your dynamic content"} />
<meta name="description" content={"Your dynamic content"} />
</Helmet>
//your content
</>)}
```